# string [,] and repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, string, repeater

How do I write out my array with a repeater?

```
string[,] month = { {"Januari", "Februari", "Mars", "Apri", "Maj", "Juni", "Juli", "Agusti", "September", "November", "Oktober", "December"},
                    {"01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12"}
                  };
```

Now I can use Container.DataItem, but how do I get the first string of items in one place and the second in another place?

```
<a href="Default.aspx?m=01">Januari</a>
```

Comment: I nominate this question for least articulate question of the day.

Comment: Welbog and apandit: how many foreign languages did you guys speak fluently when you were 17?

Comment: @Fredrik Mörk: Two, why?

Comment: Don't complain, edit! ;)

Comment: Ah, noticed that you are Canadian; that's cheating ;o) Many posters here did not have the privilege to grow up in an English speaking country, but actually has to learn it in school. I get a bit annoyed sometimes with the lack of understanding for that fact, especially when the person is young, as in this case. That may not have been your intention, but it can easily be mistaken. Especially if English is not your mother tongue. No big deal; let's get back to business.

Comment: @schnaader: It's hard to edit when you don't really have a good idea what the author intended.

Comment: Actually, the english you used wasn't too bad. I could understand it (which is why I was able to answer your question). The main problem with your question is you depend on your language to get your intention through. More code samples and some pseudo code would've probably gotten you answers much quicker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be possible to use an array of arrays as data source (but not a two dimensional array), but you would have to arrange it the other way arround, so that each inner array would contain a name and a number.

I would prefer a more OOP approach though, it gives a bit more structure and the repeater code gets a lot cleaner:

Create a class for the month information:

```
public class MonthInfo {

   public string Name { get; private set; }
   public string Number { get; private set; }

   public MonthInfo(string name, string number) {
      Name = name;
      Number = number;
   }

}
```

Now you can create an array of objects to use as data source for the repeater:

```
MonthInfo[] months = {
   new MonthInfo("Januari", "01"),
   new MonthInfo("Februari", "02"),
   new MonthInfo("Mars", "03"),
   new MonthInfo("April", "04"), // inte "Apri" ;)
   new MonthInfo("Maj", "05"),
   new MonthInfo("Juni", "06"),
   new MonthInfo("Juli", "07"),
   new MonthInfo("Augusti", "08"), // inte "Agusti" ;)
   new MonthInfo("September", "09"),
   new MonthInfo("Oktober", "10"), // kommer före november ;)
   new MonthInfo("November", "11"),
   new MonthInfo("December", "12")
};

MonthRepeater.DataSource = months;
```

In the repeater you use the properties of the month info class:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" id="MonthRepeater">
   <ItemTemplate>
      <a href="Default.aspx?m=<%#Eval("Number")>"%><%#Eval("Name")%></a>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater">
```

Comment: Det heter Augusti också, med "u" på båda sidor om "g" ;o)

Comment: "MonthIngo" should be "MonthInfo"

Comment: Corrected both. / Rättat båda. :)

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you should be using enums in this case... ie...

```
enum Month = {January=1, February, March};

Month month = Month.January;
Month alsomonth = (Month)(1); // Should work
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using 2 seperate arrays...

```
string[] month = {"Januari", "Februari"} // blah blah

string[] day = {"01", "02" } // blah blah
```

Are you working with real dates or is this just your example? Januari???

Comment: This may surprise you, but some people speak a different language than English.

Comment: @Aistina, I don't think @J.13.L was taking a crack at the OP's language.  It seemed more like curiosity.

Comment: oh... I am sorry I didn't mean any offense. I was just asking a clarification question. swedish dates, now I know. That's pretty cool!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a globalized version that avoids having to make a class etc....

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
     this.Culture = "sv-SE";
     var monthNames = System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.MonthNames.ToList();
     this.MonthRepeater.DataSource = from month in monthNames
                                select new {
                                    Number = monthNames.IndexOf(month) + 1,
                                    Name = month
                                };
     this.MonthRepeater.DataBind();
```

}

ASPX:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" id="MonthRepeater">       
   <ItemTemplate>
      <a href="Default.aspx?m<%#Eval("Number")%>"><%#Eval("Name")%></a> 
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [Dictionaries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) (there it a very convenient initialization syntax) or [enums](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc138362.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You'd better create an enum if you are really using it for Months. Then you can use <%# ((MonthsEnum)Container.DataItem).ToString() %> for the name and `<%# (int)Container.DataItem %>` for the number